# Date of Birth Check using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I am new to angular and I am not sure how to work with dates. I have a `form` with `name` and `date of birth`.

Before submission I want to check if the person is older than 18 and show an error message before the form is submitted.
But I donot have access to the `dob` variable in the `form` unless it is submitted. In my code I have access to `$scope.contact.dob` only inside `addContact()`,( after the date is submitted). How do I do date of birth validations before form submission?

My code snippet is shown below

```
    <form>
        <input ng-model="contact.name">
        <input ng-model="contact.dob" ng-min="minAge()">
        <p  ng-show="userForm.birthday.$error.min">Mustatleast 18.</p>
        <button ng-click=addContact()></button>
    </form>
```

my controller:

```
    .controller("myctrl", function($scope){
        $scope.addContact = fucntion(){
            console.log($scope.contact)
            $scope.contact.dob
        }
        $scope.minAge = function () {
            var current = new Date();
            var minYear = current.getFullYear() - 100;
            var min = new Date(minYear,current.getMonth(),current.getDate()).toISOString();
            return min;
        };

    })
```

Comment: The *minAge* function seems to be getting a date for 100 years ago. Is that what is actually required? A simpler way to get a date 18 years ago would be `current.setFullYear(current.getFullYear() -18)`. Now *current* is 18 years ago. You might want to check that the new month is the same as the old one, if not, set the date to 0 so for leap years 29 Feb - 18 years doesn't end up as 1 Mar (or maybe that's ok).

Answer (score 1):

In angular, while there is a directive for `ng-minlength`, there is no built-in-directive `ng-min`. Take a look at the documentation here.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

Instead of ng-min, use the HTML `min` attribute.

Your code should look like this

```
<input ng-model="contact.dob" min="{{minAge()}}">
```

As for the error messages, you should take a look at `ng-messages`.